# how arrays of dynamic objects differs in C++ & Java?

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I have recently learned about array of objects in Java. 
Consider this:

```
Student s[]=new student[3];
```

But why above statement just creates the array which can hold references to 3 student objects. It doesn't create student class objects themselves. I have to create them separately using the constructor of the Student class. so if i try to access any class member like this:

s[0].name="meet"

It will generate runtime error **"NullPointerException"**

But these seems odd to me because in C++ these isn't required.
Consider this C++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
class Test
{
    public:
        Test()
        {
            cout<<"Constructor\n";
        }
        void fun()
        {
            cout<<"fun() is called\n";
        }
        ~Test()
        {
            cout<<"Destructor\n";
        }
};
int main()
{
    Test* t=new Test[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        t[i].fun();
    delete[] t;
    return 0;
}
```

what happens internally when 1st statement in main() executes? if it works fine in C++ then why generates NullPointerException in java.

```
   class test
    {
          test()
          {
                 System.out.println("Constructor");
          }

          void fun()
          {
                 System.out.println("fun() is called");
          }
           public static void main(String args[])
           {
                 test t[]=new test[3];
                 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                       t[i].fun();  // oops runtime error
                 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                       t[i]=new test();
                 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                       t[i].fun();  // now fine.
           }

}
```

Why objects have to be created separately using constructor of class in java, but they need not be created separately using constructor of class in C++?

Please help me.

Comment: Java isn't C++, why do you expect it to work the same way?

Comment: There are many differences, and a few similarities. It is best to understand the semantics of arrays in each language separately.

Comment: this might help you:
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs368-2/JavaTutorial/NOTES/Java_vs.html#arrays

Comment: The Java array does not contain class instances, the C++ one does. With an equivalent indirection in C++ (i.e. an array of pointers) you would have to create the objects explicitly there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is just because the syntax is (almost the same) doesn't mean it works the same.  In fact, the statement, as you wrote it, wouldn't compile in C++ because of the [] in `Student s[]`

The equivalent C++ code to your Java code is:

```
Student** s = new Student*[3];
```

You could then initialize the students like this:

s[0] = new Student("Jimmy");

This is an important concept to grasp, because Java isn't the only programming language that differs from C++ in this manner.

Here's a full example that you can play around with.  Compiled with g++ 4.3.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Student {
public:
    Student() : name_("<unknown>") {
        std::cout << "Default constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    Student(const char* name) : name_(name) {
        std::cout << "constructor called with name '" << name << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    void setName(const std::string& name) { name_ = name; }
    const std::string& getName() const { return name_; }

private:
    std::string name_;
};

void demoArrayOfValues() {
    std::cout << "demoArrayOfValues()" << std::endl;

    // Here the default constructor will be called 3 times because
    // creating you're creating an array of objects
    Student* s =  new Student[3];

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        std::cout << "Student[" << x << "] (byValue): " << s[x].getName() << std::endl;
    }

    s[0].setName("Jimmy");
    s[1].setName("Sally");
    s[2].setName("Susie");

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        std::cout << "Student[" << x << "] (after setting): " << s[x].getName() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void demoArrayOfPointers() {
    std::cout << "demoArrayOfPointers()" << std::endl;

    // This is the C++ equivalent of the Java example that started the question
    // Here you're creating an array of pointers and have to create the objects
    // themselves
    Student** s =  new Student*[3];

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        std::cout << "Student[" << x << "] (pointer): " << s[x] << std::endl;
    }

    s[0] = new Student("Jimmy");
    s[1] = new Student("Sally");
    s[2] = new Student("Susie");

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        std::cout << "Student[" << x << "] (after creating): " << s[x]->getName() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Now we iterate over the elements in the array and delete each one.       
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        delete s[x];
    }

    // Now we delete the array itself
    delete [] s;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    demoArrayOfValues();
    demoArrayOfPointers();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: will you please explain this statement?             Student** s =  new Student*[3];
how to use delete operator to deallocate memory for above statement?

Comment: Sure.  s is a dynamically allocated array of 3 pointers to Student instances.  Initially each array element is an invalid pointer.  Therefore you'd have to set each element to a new instance (e.g. `s[0] = new Student("Jimmy");`.

Comment: I'll modify my example to properly delete the objects.  In this case you want to delete the Student instances first, then the array of pointers using delete[]

Comment: I tried http://ideone.com/0c578z this example in VC++ & it shows me garbage values not 0 0 0 as output. Why?

Comment: Good question.  The pointer values are undefined when the array is allocated.  That is different than a nullptr.